# Query nested json Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, database, postgresql

Given a model - Example - with the jsonb attribute - categories -, is it possible to query against all Examples based on the sub key of duration against any first level key.

```
ex_1 = Example.first.categories => {foo: {duration: 3}, bar: {duration: 8}}
ex_2 = Example.last.categories => {baz: {duration: 11}, bbq: {duration: 8}}
```

Trying to do something like...

```
Example.where("categories#>>'{*, duration}' = 8")
```